# How do I make my own (geo-spatial) map using React Native?

Tags: react-native

How do I make my own map on React Native? For example, a map of a shopping center with a floor plan.

Can this be implemented using `react-native-maps`? Can I make a map in 3D space?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you implement your floor plan as some sort of overlay on a geographical map, react-native-maps may not be the tool for you.

I’ve had success in the past performing this kind of task by creating the floor plan as an SVG and using react-native-svg to render it while also making use of a gesture handler library to make the containing view scrollable/zoomable.